# What am I in this rebus?

Tags: rebus

```
0
______________________
PhD
BS
AAS
```

Solve this Rebus.
See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebus

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Three degrees below zero

The abbreviations are all (college/university) degrees.